# Good application for automated testing of .Net GUIs written in C#

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, automated-tests

#### Background

The company I work for is developing a .NET Graphical User Interface (GUI) written in C# and we're almost ready to test it.

#### Question

Is there a list of standard accepted programs that do the following?

- Will be able to run automated testing of the GUI
- Integrate with VS2008 (not required)
- Create a log file of the test or testing session
- Doesn't rely on the GUI controls being at certain `x`,`y` positions?

Comment: I'm assuming this is Winforms?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no requirement for program to be free, I believe [TestComplete](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/testcomplete/) is good choice.
Our test team uses it for both Winforms and WPF applications.

Answer (score 1):

A new open source project has all the above (including VS 2008 plugin) check it out:
[QAliber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qaliber/)

Enjoy,
Guy.

Answer (score 0):

Try UIAutomation framework. It works better with WPF controls compared with standard Winforms controls(assuming your app is Winforms).

Edit: Our testing team uses Mercury's AutomatedQA.

Answer (score 0):

I know Borland Silk, or whatever they call Borland now, has a good testing suite. It cost a bit of money and learning curve. But, a lot of QA types know it.

Comment: Same for HP QuickTestPro and IBM RationalRobot. HP QTP probably leads here. None has MSVS integration but they pass rest of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use [3rdParty](http://white.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Is%20White%20the%20right%20choice&referringTitle=Home) controls, [white](http://www.codeplex.com/white) might be the open source UIAutomation tool you want to try.
It is build on top of the .Net UIAutomation framework and needs the .NET 3.0 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Windows.Automation to deal with GUI controls by their ID's instead of their locations... but I prefer using [this program and tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163465.aspx) which greatly simplifies the interactions.

You have to dig around to get the UISpy executable to identify the ids properly.  I typically just add my GUI tests to my NUnit test suites.  Works ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is the White project. Before that there was NUnit Forms. I think these have been the main open source tools for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have described my experiences with developing a tool for GUI automated testing in a serie on my blog: http://gui-at.blogspot.com/search/label/guiat. The tool is developed in [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/).

The following articles are helfpull too:

- [Acceptance Testing .NET Applications using IronPython](http://tartley.com/?p=1018) by Jonathan Hartley
- [Functional Testing of GUI Applications](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/testing/) by Michael Foord

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a free and open source solution and your team can invest time to develop automated tests then your team can try Winium. It has a C# library that can be downloaded from Nuget and along with Nunit can fulfill your requirements listed above.

Here are some useful links to get started.
https://github.com/2gis/Winium and https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop that you might find useful. Check out this you tube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9HTCMhuLwM

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "standard accepted programs".

I currently use WinTask for that sort of testing, but it depends on what you are trying to accomplish, the background of the person performing the tests, etc, etc.